# Extracting date from output of date function

Tags: regex

My requirement is as follows:
I have three strings say

```
string 1 : "February Friday 07"
string 2 : "02 Friday 07 two thousand fourteen"
String 3: "Friday 07 February"
```

Would like to know the regexp to extract the date (in above case number "07") from those three strings.

Comment: Give your code , and what you tried.

Comment: Actually, I have strings in different languages as well

Comment: String 1 (English):"February Friday 07", String 2(Chinese tradition) :"2星期四, 二月 07".  To extract it, I use /([0-9]+)/ and to access it with $1, But it always getting me the first displayed number (i.e in English 07, in Chinese it is 02. But I want 07 in Chinese too)

Comment: Sorry, I pasted wrong string earlier.  My Second string is (Chinese tradition)is "02 月 07 日 星期四". And I am using javascript, in which I need to find out date and apply bold for it. Something like somevar.replace(/([0-9]+)/, '<b>$1</b>'). But as I said earlier, it always extract first number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
 (?:mon|tues|wednes|thurs|fri|satur|sun)day\s(\d+)
```

Check **[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oJ5nH0)**

**Explanation :**

[image]